# Изменение вида даты

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Возможно вопрос очень простой, но сам никак осилить не могу. Есть стандартный вид даты **2017-04-24**. Нужно его разделить и обернуть все в тег с классом. Сделать хочу что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, после разделения года, месяца и даты, нужно месяц заменить на текст. Под это дело прикрутил массив с месяцами, а вот как сделать замену никак не пойму. Просьба так же посмотреть на саму реализацию кода, можно ли сократить? Есть ли ошибки? JQ подключен.

```js
var date = $(".date").html();
var monthName = new Array ("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");
var newdate="";
date=date.split('-');
for(i=0;i<date.length;i++ ){
newdate= '<span class="year">' +date[0]+ '</span> <span class="month">' +date[1]+ '</span> <span class="day">' +date[2]+ '</span>';
}
$(".date").html(newdate);
```

```css
.year {
color: red;
}
.month {
color: blue;
}
.day {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">2017-03-13</div>
<div class="date">2014-12-13</div>
```

Можно ли дополнить этот скрипт, чтоб он изменял вид даты для нескольких элементов с датой на странице? Или потребуется полностью изменить функцию? Это в общем-то не особо и нужно, на всякий случай)

Благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для наглядности форматирование можно вынести в отдельную функцию - `formatDate`.

А так - у вас все правильно, только вместо самого номера месяца подставляете значение из массива месяцев (не забывая, что индексация начинается с 0):

```js
$(".date").each(function() {
  $(this).html( formatDate($(this).html()) );
});


function formatDate(date) {
  var monthName = ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"];
  var newdate="";
  date = date.split('-');
  for(i=0;i<date.length;i++ ){
    newdate= '<span class="year">' +date[0]+ '</span> <span class="month">' +monthName[date[1]-1]+ '</span> <span class="day">' +date[2]+ '</span>';
  }
 return newdate;
}
```

```css
.year {
color: red;
}
.month {
color: blue;
}
.day {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">2017-03-13</div>
<div class="date">2014-12-13</div>
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Все просто:

```
monthName[date[1]-1]
```

`-1` тк индекс массива начинается с 0

```js
var date = $(".date").html();
var monthName = new Array ("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");
var newdate="";
date=date.split('-');
for(i=0;i<date.length;i++ ){
newdate= '<span class="year">' +date[0]+ '</span> <span class="month">' +monthName[date[1]-1]+ '</span> <span class="day">' +date[2]+ '</span>';
}
$(".date").html(newdate);
```

```css
.year {
color: red;
}
.month {
color: blue;
}
.day {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">2017-03-13</div>
<div class="date">2014-12-13</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оказалось все довольно просто и понятно)